# How to install a package greater than or equal to a particular version

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

A script requires a ruby version greater than or equal to 1.9. How do I translate that to apt command? Tried below, does not work:

```
 % sudo apt-get install "ruby ( >= 1.9.1 )"
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ruby ( >


 % sudo apt-get install "ruby>=1.9.1"      
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ruby>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`apt` does not support specifying version ranges to install a package. You can only either specify the exact version you want it to take, or you omit the version to let it decide automatically.

To find out what versions of a package are available for you, the output of

```
apt policy PACKAGENAME
```

will be helpful, e.g. for `ruby` on 16.04:

```
ruby:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:2.3.0+1
  Version table:
     1:2.3.0+1 500
        500 http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
```

The version above corresponds to Ruby 2.3 btw.

So in this example, you could install either `ruby` to let the system automatically pick the only available version, or you could specify it explicitly as `ruby=1:2.3.0+1`.

The command to install the desired package will be one of

```
sudo apt install PACKAGENAME
sudo apt install PACKAGENAME=VERSION
```

Comment: What about dpkg/aptitude or other tools that can be used to install a package in ubuntu?

Comment: No, `aptitude` doesn't offer such an option either. `dpkg` on the other hand is just a tool to install an already downloaded `.deb` package file. It does not fetch the package for you, like `apt` or `aptitude` do, so you can not specify any version at all, because the version is determined by what you manually downloaded yourself.

Comment: Aptitude can be use to forbid a specific version. `aptitude forbid-version vim=1.2.3.broken-4`; however, this only works if using aptitude for upgrades, it doesn't get applied at lower levels. You can `pin` a specific version with a negative priority and that will prevent it's installation.

Answer (score 4):

In my case `apt satisfy` was perfect for installing python3 version greater-equal 3.9.

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt satisfy "python3 (>= 3.9), python3-dev (>= 3.9)"
```

Also this can help with broken dependencies.